# GHC Foreign hs_init/hs_add_root crashes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, haskell, dll, linker, ghc

I don't repeat more than necessary, brief summary:
Following the [`Adder` example from this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/satnam_singh/archive/2011/04/19/creating-a-windows-dll-from-a-haskell-program-and-calling-it-from-c.aspx) on a machine with win7 (64) with VS 2010.
But I don't use C++ but plain C.

When using the `cl` (MS compiler) with `cl /Zi` (and no other flag) it works like expected.
If not use `/Zi`  and then try to execute the exe goes into flames.

Why? 
(There must be some compiler/link options that make some init in the start of the haskell dll go wrong )

EDIT:
Some investigation:

`/Zi` does not affect optimizations. However, `/Zi` does imply `/debug`; see [`/DEBUG` (Generate Debug Info)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/958x11bc.aspx) for more information.

`/DEBUG` [changes the defaults for the `/OPT` option from `REF` to `NOREF` and from `ICF` to `NOICF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe4t6fc1.aspx) (so, you will need to explicitly specify `/OPT:REF` or `/OPT:ICF`).]

`/OPT:ICF` can result in the same address being assigned to different functions or read only data members (const variables compiled with `/Gy`). So, `/OPT:ICF` can break a program that depends on the address of functions or read-only data members being different. See [`/Gy` (Enable Function-Level Linking)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976.aspx) for more information.

Can someone confirm that `/OPT:ICF` will affect the loading of a Haskell/GHC compiled shared library(dll) ?

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem?

Comment: @morechilli with /OPT:NOREF /OPT:NOICF  as arguments to the linker when building my main program  the dll works.

Comment: thanks following your suggestion my trivial program now works with just the /OPT:NOREF change.